# cannot find package from goroot gopath

Tags: go, package

if i download external library **(ex. go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin)**

it goes to **c:\Users\username\go\pkg\mod**  not  **c:\Users\username\go\src**

Inside the go\pkg\mod folder, it has external library

i got error like this

```
could not import github.com/gin-gonic/gin (cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of 
    C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\gin-gonic\gin (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Users\dusrj\go\src\github.com\gin-gonic\gin (from $GOPATH))
```

My GOPATH & GOROOT is as follows

```
go env GOPATH
-> C:\Users\dusrj\go

go env GOROOT
-> C:\Program Files\Go
```

If I manipulate environment variables in the system window and change GOPATH to the following,

**C:\Users\dusrj\go\pkg\mod**

error message is changed like this

```
could not import ...
    ...omitted...
    C:\Users\dusrj\go\pkg\mod\src\github.com\gin-gonic\gin (from $GOPATH))
```

The weird thing is that sometimes there is no error

Creating an src folder in a C:\Users\dusr\go path and copying and pasting the github folder in it didn't worked for me

go mod init also didn't worked for me

OS: Window10,
Go version: 1.17.6
IDE: vsocde

Any help would be highly appreciated.
thank U :)

Comment: `go get` no longer downloads anything, and nothing should ever be in `$GOPATH/src`. Make sure you have setup your module as shown in the documentation: [Getting Started](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started.html), or [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code.html)